# Regression: Predicting values over orders of magnitudes - what metric(s) to use?

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

What is a good metric to use for predicting values over several orders of magnitude?

I can use R^2 but other measures like mean absolute error or mean squared error are pretty meaningless. In my case a lot of the low values are over-estimated. For example value is 0.03 but prediction is 0.2 (approx. 1 order of magnitude) or 0.1 vs. 4 (again approx 1 order of magnitude). For higher values the absolute error is bigger but it's more accurate in terms of order of magnitudes.

Almost forgot to mention: Due to other issue (prediction of negative values which make no sense) the actual model is trained using log values and not the actual values to avoid negative predictions.

To repeat the question: What are meaningful options for metrics?

Comment: Your "almost forgot to mention" is crucial here. Whenever values cannot be negative, working on log scale is usually the answer. You can use generalised linear models with logarithmic link to get the best of both worlds, as it were fitting on logarithmic scale but predicting on the original scale. Important detail: can values ever be zero? In terms of metrics,  values on log scale and on the original scale can both be useful.

Comment: No 0 isn't possible but very low values. Albeit anything that is interesting won't be below approx. 0.01.